# java JFrame setSize

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am loading a JFrame showing the company logo and credits etc before starting the main application. I am having some problems. Fist of all, the size of my new JFrame can never be set. The JFrame looked fine when I previewed it under netBean but came out smaller every time. I tried to do it with a new constructor and setSize(), but still not working. Second, the JFrame has been loaded very slowly. No images and everything could be loaded and the JFrame stays blank for at least five seconds, really kind of annoying. Do it have anything to do with where I put the image files? 
Thanks alot.

Comment: Let us try to help you by seeing your code or something, how is my offer?

Comment: Use another layout other than the default GroupLayout. There are many to choose from, and they are usually more flexible in this situation than GroupLayout.

Comment: If you're using Java 6+ you don't need to roll your own splashscreen any more - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 3):

> I am loading a JFrame showing the company logo and credits etc before starting the main application. I am having some problems. Fist of all, the size of my new JFrame can never be set. The JFrame looked fine when I previewed it under netBean but came out smaller every time. I tried to do it with a new constructor and setSize(), but still not working.

It is very difficult to suss out what is wrong without seeing your code, but having said that, your comment about this being a NetBeans-generated GUI suggests that the code will be very large and hard to read and interpret. It is for this and many other reasons that I am not a fan of using NetBeans to generate GUI's, especially for newbies who are just learning how to use Swing. I suggest that you write out your GUI code by hand with some user-friendly layout managers, nested by nesting JPanels if necessary. If you do it this way, you'll have some greater flexibility and control in the construction of your GUI, and you'll also have readable and debuggable code that you can post here for our assessment and help should it not work out right for you.

> Second, the JFrame has been loaded very slowly. No images and everything could be loaded and the JFrame stays blank for at least five seconds, really kind of annoying. Do it have anything to do with where I put the image files? Thanks alot.

This sounds like a threading issue. I'd just load the images for the intro GUI first, then show the intro window, and then in a background thread, load any other resources that the program needs.

Having said all this, you probably want to look into using Java's own [splash screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) as this may do all that you're trying to cobble together on your own.  The tutorials can help you with this (please click on link above or [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Much unclear question description though I want to point some tips...

> Do it have anything to do with where I put the image files?

If you mean your JFrame title image so you can use its [setIconImage()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method

> Fist of all, the size of my new JFrame can never be set.

It is quite strange :( because you can always write code like a

```
JFrame aFrame=new JFrame();
aFrame.setSize(x,y);
```

... to control your frame scale

> Second, the JFrame has been loaded very slowly. No images and
>   everything could be loaded and the JFrame stays blank for at least
>   five seconds

It may be caused by single thread overloaded but still to analyze the problem show the main class code or its exceptions stack trace

> previewed it under netBean but came out smaller every time

what component do you use to paint your logo? And how do you paint it? Show the snippet

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I actually put the images on JLabels because I need to load more than one. I tried setSize() with a new constructor and after I create a new JFrame and both does not work.

Comment: You can use setIcon() method to change images with no need to repain the whole component (of course, if you do so); And don't use JFrame as the only one JLabel containing component; I recommend you just to use the bound like "JFrame (GridLayout) -> JPanel (GridLayout) -> JLabel (setIcon(...))"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size by right click on the jFrame and 
    Set Default size
(netbeans design view)
I hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful for you?

```
    JPanel aa = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    aa.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    aa.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(490,490));
    aa.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates.

Comment: hi, thesee questions have same topic, so answers may be same.

Answer (score -1):

I opened the properties dialog for my JFrame and set "minimum size" field to [500,500] but that did not work.

What did work for me was selecting the "..." button at the right of the "minimum size" property. In the "JFrame Mininumsize" dialog as follows:

1. set dropdown (Set forms minimum size property using: ) = "Custom Code"
2. set code in (Form.setMinimumSize( )  ) = "new Dimensiom(500,500)"